# How to understand Aposematism and Batesian mimicry

Tags: evolution

**EDIT** I want to understand the reason for intense animal colors. I.e. I don't want to understand the variety of the colors, just the intensity.

The [Wikipedia page for Cethosia biblis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cethosia_biblis#Description) says, the intense colors are a "warning" to enemies, which means the enemy is warned by the colors that eating that butterfly may result in death.

> [...], while the intense color of the dorsal sides of the wings is a warning
>   to predators that the Red Lacewing has a bad taste, deriving from the
>   poisonous host plants of the caterpillars.

In general it would make sense to me, that animals have learned something like "intense colors means danger". Although, I don't know how good animals recognize colors, but that would be another question.

But poisonous animals don't have necessarily intense colors. E.g. Sydney funnel web spider is very poisonous, but doesn't have intense colors, while on the other side some very intense colored butterflies are not poisonous like explained [here](http://www.kidsbutterfly.org/faq/general/5). As a result, the explanation given in the wikipedia article doesn't make sense to me. I estimate it very unlikely, that animals learned something like "intense colors means danger", because there are of course examples where this is not true.

Therefore, I don't think the "Golden poison frog" has survived because his enemies recognize his intense colors and conclude "eating this frog will result in death" are hence hesitated to eat him.

**My question is:** Why does wikipedia say then, the intense colors of Cethosia biblis are a warning for their enemies?

**PS:** I just found the correct terms for my thoughts ("aposematism" and "batesian mimicry" and are reading now the appropriate wikipedia article. I didn't knew them when I've asked this question.

PPS: to avoid confusion: @DavidBlomstrom answered this version of my question https://biology.stackexchange.com/revisions/42554/2

Comment: The question is hard to understand because it is a a bit poorly phrased. I would advice that you 1) start you sentences with capitalized letters. 2) Introduce a quotation before actually quoting. 3) Clarify the intention behind the use of `"` around the term "warning signal" or just remove them. 4) Clarify what you mean by "warning signal" 5) Don't use `==>` but use language to express causation. 6) Clarify what you mean by "survival of the scar" 7) Use capitalized `I` for the first person in singular.

Comment: 8) Make sure you make sentences. For example this: `I mean, i doubt a simple "survival of the scar", because of the colorful, but not poisonous animals.` is not a sentence. Being ESL (which I also am) might not help. I am voting to close as unclear.

Comment: While I don't understand the question I suppose that your question (assuming you know what you really want to ask) is very broad and is something `Why are there so many colors?`. As you are talking about toxic animals, you might want to focus on them and try to understand why they are colorful. Btw, poisonous and toxic are not synonym.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i've updated my question accordingly. @Remi.b why are "poisonous" and "toxic" not synonym? [The cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/poisonous) lists "poisonous" as alternative term for toxic.